# SwiftData: Use ObjectID URIRepresentation to load CoreData object?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-data

I am replacing some CoreData code within my iOS App to use the new SwiftData framework. In my original code, I was saving a CoreData object URI in UserDefaults for a quick bookmark. This allowed me to easily fetch specific object I needed directly.

e.g.

```swift
model.objectID().uriRepresentation().absoluteString
```

While investigating a SwiftData solution, I came across this `objectID` property on SwiftData models, which is of type `PersistentIdentifier`, which seems to do what I want. But there doesn't seem to a straight forward way to bookmark this value. `PersistentIdentifier` conforms to the "Codeable", which I could save to UserDeafaults, by converting it to `Data`, but when I attempt to do that, the returned value doesn't include any of the necessary data, just an empty values. This is what is created when encoding the `id` or `objectID` of the Model object.

```swift
"{\"implementation\":{}}"
```

How can I accomplish this with the new SwiftData framework?

Comment: To me it looks like the encode (and decode?) functionality hasn't been implemented yet for PersistentIdentifier. I can clearly see in the debugger that the `objectID` property contains data but I get the same empty result when I encode it.

Comment: Yep. I saw the same thing. I curious why or how since it seems to be using standard Swift foundation types. I guess they are not using the compiler generated Encode/Decode implementation and just have empty functions or something?

Comment: My guess is that something is expected to change in the structure or data of the type so they have created this dummy encoding so we won’t encode data that we later on can’t decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in Xcode 15 Beta 5 Codable is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Until Apple provides this, here is a temporary solution that seems to work well:

```
extension PersistentIdentifier {

    public func uriRepresentation() -> URL? {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
           let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoded) as? [String: Any],
           let implementation = dictionary["implementation"] as? [String: Any],
           let uriRepresentation = implementation["uriRepresentation"] as? String {
            return URL(string: uriRepresentation)
        } else {
            return  nil
        }
    } }
```

FYI, unlike the Core Data method, I made the result of my uriRepresentation extension an Optional to suit the needs of my App.

Comment: Obviously this is now obsolete since PersistentIdentifier works as expected with Codable.